# DbContext fails to initialize Model-first database

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-model-first

**Update**: It turns out I had (hidden away in my POCO objects) a property with an abstract type. Removing this property solves the issue.

---

I'm trying to have a model-first scenario with entity framework 4 ctp 5 generate my database (currently using a SQL Server CE4 backend, but I can reproduce on a Sql Server 2008 backend) from my model.

I think I might have messed up my model definition somehow, but I can't seem to figure out how and the error message leaves me none the wiser.

My DbContext object is set up as such:

```
public class MyDb : DbContext
{
    public MyDb()
    {
        // Apply forced recreation tactics for now
        DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyDb>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDb>());
    }

    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OtherData> OtherDatas { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

When I query it (as follows):

```
        MyDb db = new MyDb();
        var matchingAccount = from user in db.UserAccounts where user.Email == email select user;
        return matchingAccount.SingleOrDefault();
```

I get the following error:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot
>   be null. Parameter name: entitySet]
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +9591079
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +371    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
>   +16    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +15
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>   +62    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_Provider()
>   +15    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +13    System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate) +63

However, the first time I build, this is the specific error:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot
>   be null. Parameter name: entitySet]
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.RuntimeFailureMethods.ReportFailure(ContractFailureKind
>   contractFailureKind, String
>   userMessage, String conditionText,
>   Exception innerException) +970860
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Db.Mapping.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.GetEntitySetMapping(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping, EdmEntitySet
>   entitySet) +147
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.EntityTypeMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmEntityType
>   entityType, DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping) +206
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(EdmModel
>   model, DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping) +253
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel
>   model) +168
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.GenerateDatabaseMapping(EdmModel
>   model, DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest) +233
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbProviderInfo
>   providerInfo, Boolean validateModel)
>   +280    System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) +173
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel()
>   +61

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going crazy wondering why my db had stopped working.  Just yesterday I had added an abstract class as a property to one of my domain objects.  Back to the interfaces I think!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the

```
 // Apply forced recreation tactics for now
        DbDatabase.SetInitializer<BudgetnetDatabase>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BudgetnetDatabase>());
```

should only be applied once in your project. i suggest you move this code out of the class.

is there more to your db context?

any configuration?

is it possible to see  BudgetnetDatabase ?

we will also need to see the poco objects.

is the database getting create at all?

Comment: The SetInitializer was actually in the static constructor. I moved it to see if that was the problem. I have 6 POCO classes. Each of them contain public primitive/string properties. A single enumeration type property wrapped using the technique from [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/05/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4.aspx](Alex James' blog). Relationsships are all of the form `public virtual ICollection<PocoObject>`and each PocoObject class has a corresponding `DbSet` property in the context. The database is NOT being created.